# Using html entities in mobile webapp

Tags: jquery, html, web-applications, mobile, entities

I created a simple webapp using jQuery Mobile 1.2.
Now I want to know whether it is better to use html entities in page body or should I write texts with all characters in utf-8 charset? Both ways work correct but which one is usual?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `characters in utf-8 charset` surely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the UTF-8 character, believe me I have used jquery mobile and text with UTF-8 are better than with HTML

Answer (score 2):

UTF-8 should be your choice. Better, safer and modern.

Answer (score 0):

Use entities only for symbols messing with your HTML markup.
like `< > ...`